# How to resolve this simple pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the following PDE:
$$u_{xx} + u_{xt} − 20u_{tt} = 0.$$
On factorizing the operators we get that 
$$(∂_x + 5∂_t)(∂_x − 4∂_t)u = 0.$$
If we let 
$$\alpha = ax+bt$$
$$\beta = cx+dt.$$
Then by the chain rule 
$$\partial_{x} = a\partial_{\alpha}+b\partial_{\beta}$$ and 
$$\partial_{t} = c\partial_{\alpha}+d\partial_{\beta}.$$
Thus
$$(∂_x + 5∂_t)(∂_x − 4∂_t) = ((a+5c)\partial_{\alpha+}+(b+5d)\partial_{t})((a-4c)\partial_{\alpha+}+(b-4d)\partial_{t}).$$
We choose $c=1,a=4,d=1$ and $b=-5.$ Then
$$(∂_x + 5∂_t)(∂_x − 4∂_t) = (9\partial_{\alpha})(-9\partial_{\beta})=0.$$ Thus $$u(x,y)=f(\alpha)+g(\beta)=f(4x-5t)+g(x+t).$$ 
We check this 
$$u_{xx} = 16f''+g$$ 
$$u_{xt} = -20f''+g''$$
$$u_{tt} = 25f''+g''.$$ On substituting this solution does not work. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: $\alpha = ax+bt\implies \partial_{\alpha}=a\partial_x+b\partial_t.$ I don't see why it is $\partial_{x} = a\partial_{\alpha}+b\partial_{\beta}.$

Comment: I solved on paper but I got different equations. You need to re-check. Am new to this community so will start learning how to post equations here.